# exact number of random image(d) buttons in java

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

i was wondering how can i make a grid of 2x10 with 20 buttons which every button is attached to an image (in java). I must make those buttons by randomly choosing an image, but every button has to appear exact number of times ,that means that every button has a random image from a range of images (i've done that by shuffling the images) and also that button of a specific image can be more than one times.

e.g :

```
button with im9 must appear 4 times

button with im7 must appear 1 times
```

is there a way to do that without having to sum all the times of the appearence of every button-image?

p.s: i'm new to java, please pe polite. I didn't really know how to title my question , i may not have done that right.

Comment: Ok let me give you an idea on the anwser just wait a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Ok im not done will edit this soon but this is how you create the 2*10 grid:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TicTacToe {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton row1col1, row1col2, row1col3, row2col1, row2col2, row2col3;
    private JButton row3col1, row3col2, row3col3, row4col1, row4col2, row4col3;
    private JButton row5col1, row5col2, row5col3, row6col1, row6col2, row6col3;
    //private JButton row7col1, row7col2, row7col3;

    public TicTacToe() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        frame = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        row1col1 = new JButton();
        row1col1.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row1col1);

        row1col2 = new JButton();
        row1col2.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row1col2);

        row1col3 = new JButton();
        row1col3.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row1col3);

        row2col1 = new JButton();
        row2col1.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row2col1);

        row2col2 = new JButton();
        row2col2.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row2col2);

        row2col3 = new JButton();
        row2col3.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row2col3);

        row3col1 = new JButton();
        row3col1.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row3col1);

        row3col2 = new JButton();
        row3col2.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row3col2);

        row3col3 = new JButton();
        row3col3.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row3col3);

        row4col1 = new JButton();
        row4col1.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row4col1);

        row4col2 = new JButton();
        row4col2.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row4col2);

        row4col3 = new JButton();
        row4col3.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row4col3);

        row5col1 = new JButton();
        row5col1.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row5col1);

        row5col2 = new JButton();
        row5col2.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row5col2);

        row5col3 = new JButton();
        row5col3.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row5col3);

        row6col1 = new JButton();
        row6col1.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row6col1);

        row6col2 = new JButton();
        row6col2.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row6col2);

        row6col3 = new JButton();
        row6col3.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.add(row6col3);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void runGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        TicTacToe greeting = new TicTacToe();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Methods that create and show a GUI should be
         run from an event-dispatching thread */
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: why do that when you can use a for loop?

Comment: You could if you want to... But i just did it like this. Does this help?

Comment: i'm having problem with the second part of my question...i've already made the grid and given the random images to the buttons, but i cannot figure out how to make exact number of each one without having to write so many if s.

Comment: i cant understand your question @frog

Comment: i have 20 buttons to make ..let's say the names of the images are "im1, im2, im3..im9" and the buttons b1,b2,.....b20. i shuffle the images so i get " im3, im9, im1..." to get them random....and then  i want to make 4 buttons with im2 , 1button with im9 ...etc

Comment: @frog so you want to know how to put an image in an JButton?